# Return index of the smallest value in a vector?

Tags: r

```
a <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 7)
```

I am looking for a function to return the index of the smallest value, 3. What is it?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You're looking for `which.min()`:

```
a <- c(1,2,0,3,7,0,0,0)
which.min(a)
# [1] 3

which(a == min(a))
# [1] 3 6 7 8
```

(As you can see from the above, when several elements are tied for the minimum, `which.min()` only returns the index of the first one. You can use the second construct if you instead want the indices of all elements that match the minimum value.)

Comment: ...yes I was wondering how can I get the indices of all minimum elements? I need to find out how many are the minimum, perfect! Got me some time to understand this, thanks.

Comment: @hhh -- To find out how many elements are the minimum, you can just use: `sum(a == min(a))`.

Answer (score 20):

As an alternative to Josh's answer

```
a <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 7)
which(a == min(a))
```

this gives every index that is equal to the minimum value.  So if we had more than one value matching the lowest value

```
a <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 7, 0)
which(a == min(a))  # returns both 3 and 6
which.min(a)        # returns just 3
```

Edit:  If what you're looking for is just how many elements are equal to the minimum (as you imply in one of the comments) you can do this instead:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 0, 3, 7, 0)
sum(a == min(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are a fan of efficiency, then you can use the function min_max from the **Rfast** package, with index = True

It will return the index of the minimum and the index of the maximum 
value, simultaneously, faster than what has been disused so far.

E.g.

```
a = runif(10000)
Rfast::min_max(a,index=T)

# min  max 
# 2984 2885

which(a == min(a))

#[1] 2984

a = runif(1000000)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    min_max = Rfast::min_max(a,index=T),
    which1 = which(a == min(a)),
    which2 = which.min(a)
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
min_max 1.889293  1.9123860  2.08242647  1.9271395  2.0359730   3.527565   100
 which1 9.809527 10.0342505 13.16711078 10.3671640 14.7839955 111.424664   100
 which2 2.400745  2.4216995  2.66374110  2.4471435  2.5985265   4.259249   100
```

Comment: unfortunately `Rfast::min_max` will also return only one (first? does not seem documented) tie, so not fair to compare to `which(a == min(a))`, which is only relevant when one wants all mins!