# find index of minimum value greater than 0

Tags: r

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390749/return-index-of-the-smallest-value-in-a-vector), but i am wondering why it is not working in my case

I have this vector:

```
num<-c(0.000000, 4.220190, 1.421267, 1.004988, 5.060632, 1.100000, 3.744329, 5.728001, 4.707441, 4.100000, 5.200961, 5.060632, 2.282542
  ,1.676305, 0.509902, 0.781025, 2.968164, 5.916925, 5.235456, 5.371220)
```

and then i am trying to find minimum value greater than 0 which is `0.509902`
so i have

```
which.min(num > 0)
```

but it gives me

```
1
```

the index of `0.00`

Comment: It gives you 1 because you are searching for the min between TRUE and FALSE (coerced to logical once you did `num > 0`) which is FALSE which is your first element.

Comment: Not a complete duplicate as it doesn't show how to find the index but [here it is just for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615439/find-minimum-non-zero-value-in-a-column-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replace the values less than or equal to 0 with `NA` and use the `which.min`

```
i1 <- which.min(replace(num, num<=0, NA))
i1
#[1] 15
```

Or slightly more compact way is

```
which.min(num*NA^(num <=0))
#[1] 15


num[i1]
#[1] 0.509902
```

Comment: Also consider `order(num)[num != 0][1]`